# How do I test async functions with doctest?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, doctest

Example code:

```
async def test():
  """
  >>> await test()
  hello world
  """
  print("hello world")
```

Attempting to run this with doctests results in `SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doctest runs the code in the code outside any function.
You can't use await expressions outside of an async function.

In order to run async functions, you can use `asyncio.run()` like so:

```
import asyncio

async def test():
  """
  >>> asyncio.run(test())
  hello world
  """
  print("hello world")
```